# "body":"[API] This action requires merchant approval for read_customers scope."

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I am new in Shopify development and getting that error while trying to get customers using the code:

```
$id = '5207879811243';
    $shop = Auth::user();
    $request = $shop->api()->rest('GET', '/admin/api/customers/search.json', ['customers' => "id:{$id}"]);
    return $request;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEFORE you make any API calls you have to do the following:

- for a **private** App, make sure you have **read_customers** scope ticked off
- for a **public** App, make sure your oAuth scopes include the **read_customers** scope

There are plenty of documents from Shopify showing you App Scopes.

Answer (score 1):

Add Scopes in shopify.app.toml file Like:

```
scopes = "read_customers,write_customers"
```

[https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/cli/structure#root-configuration-file:~:text=in%20the%20app.-,Root%20configuration%20file,-Anchor%20link%20to](https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/tools/cli/structure#root-configuration-file:%7E:text=in%20the%20app.-,Root%20configuration%20file,-Anchor%20link%20to)

Comment: This has solved the problem for my local development version of the app!